# Getting parent div sibling tag

Tags: jquery

I want to write a function such that when class `clipartcategory` clicked above of it is `<h3>` tag and inside it is `<a>` tag i want to get the contents of `<a>`. Following is my code

```
<h3><a href="#section1">Arrows</a></h3>
<div>
    <ul>
    <li class="clipartcategory">Custom</li>
    <li class="clipartcategory">Standard</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3><a href="#section2">Borders</a></h3>
<div>
    <ul>
    <li class="clipartcategory">CornersStandard</li><li class="clipartcategory">Embellished Outline</li>
    <li class="clipartcategory">Simple Outline</li><li class="clipartcategory">Solid</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know parent function will give me `<div>` but how could i reach above of its `<h3>` and get `<a>` contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is always going to follow that structure:

```
$(".clipartcategory").click(function() {
    var aText = $(this).closest("div").prev().find("a").text();
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrVvE/). You mentioned the `parent` method in your question. I've used [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) because the `div` is not the parent of `.clipartcategory`. The `closest` method will find the closest ancestor element that matches the selector.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

@James Allardice is perfectly correct. I just give another solution of that problem:

```
$(".clipartcategory").click(function() {
    var acontent = $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("a").text();
});
```

You may also use `.html()` in replace of `.text()` if you think there might contain html tag with text.